# Intersecting Eulero-Venn diagrams at the bottom plus arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm struggling to produce a picture like this with TIKZ. The usual Eulero-Venn diagrams intersect at the center. I want them to make the intersection at the bottom, so there is space for the arrows. I tried my best with WORD here. Ideally, the two diagrams should be less skewed. [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe you could link to some description of "Eulero-Vienn diagrams" (I'm just familiar with Euler or Venn diagrams). If you don't need a special package you could just draw this with simple tikz comands: ellipse (rotated by some angle), nodes and arrows.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Is "Eulero" a variant (Italian??) spelling of the surname of Leonhard Euler?

Comment: @Mico, yes it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome. Maybe this is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt},>=latex]
 \draw[rotate=45] (-1.28,0) circle (1 and 2) 
    ++ (0,0.4) foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {++ (0,0.3) node[bullet] (L\X){}};
 \draw[rotate=-45] (1.28,0) circle (1 and 2)
  ++ (0,0.4) foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {++ (0,0.3) node[bullet] (R\X){} };
 \draw foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {(L\X) edge[thick,->] (R\X)};
 \draw foreach \X in {1,2} { (0,-1.2-0.3*\X) node[bullet] (M\X){}
    edge[thick,->,loop right] (M\X)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]